# merge some complex hashes in ruby

Tags: ruby, hash, hash-of-hashes

I'd like to merge the following hashes together.

```
 h1 = {"201201" => {:received => 2},   "201202" => {:received => 4 }}
 h2 = {"201201" => {:closed => 1},  "201202" => {:closed => 1 }}
```

particularly, my expected result is:

```
h1 = {"201201" => {:received => 2, :closed => 1},  "201202" => {:received => 4, :closed => 1 }}
```

I have tried every way as:

```
h = h1.merge(h2){|key, first, second| {first , second} }
```

unfortunately, neither seemed to work out fine for me.
any advice would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
h = h1.merge(h2){|key, first, second| first.merge(second)}
```

Comment: Ah, the block form of [`Hash#merge`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-merge) is such a beautiful thing.

Comment: If you wanted recursive merging: `m=->(k,a,b){ a.merge(b,&m) }; h = m[nil,h1,h2]`