# Merge values of 2 hashes into 1 using Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash-of-hashes

I have 2 hashes of hashes that I need to combine on values using Ruby

```
hoh = Hash.new
hoh = {"bob::params::search_vol_grp"=>{2=>{"search_group_id"=>2, "vol_ids"=>"2,627,628", "num_shards"=>32, "num_replicas"=>1}, 3=>{"search_group_id"=>3, "vol_ids"=>"3,629,630", "num_shards"=>32, "num_replicas"=>1}, 4=>{"search_group_id"=>4, "vol_ids"=>"4,631,632", "num_shards"=>32, "num_replicas"=>1}}
hob = Hash.new
hob = {"bob::params::search_q_broker"=>{2=>{"master_host"=>"hq01p1", "master_port"=>"61616", "slave_host"=>"hq01p2", "slave_port"=>"61616"}, 3=>{"master_host"=>"hq01p1", "master_port"=>"61616", "slave_host"=>"hq01p2", "slave_port"=>"61616"}, 4=>{"master_host"=>"hq01p1", "master_port"=>"61616", "slave_host"=>"hsq01p2", "slave_port"=>"61616"}}
```

What I'd like to end up with is the following -

```
hon = Hash.new
hon = {"bob::params::search"=>{2=>{"master_host"=>"hq01p1", "master_port"=>"61616", "slave_host"=>"hq01p2", "slave_port"=>"61616", "search_group_id"=>2, "vol_ids"=>"2,627,628", "num_shards"=>32, "num_replicas"=>1}, 3=>{"master_host"=>"hq01p1", "master_port"=>"61616", "slave_host"=>"hq01p2", "slave_port"=>"61616", "search_group_id"=>3, "vol_ids"=>"3,629,630", "num_shards"=>32, "num_replicas"=>1}, 4=>{"master_host"=>"hq01p1", "master_port"=>"61616", "slave_host"=>"hq01p2", "slave_port"=>"61616", "search_group_id"=>4, "vol_ids"=>"4,631,632", "num_shards"=>32, "num_replicas"=>1}}
```

I've tried various attempts at using merge and merge! but none of yielded the end result I'm looking for.

Any tips?

**EDIT**
Using the suggestion from Larry, I was able to achieve what I wanted with the following

```
hon = Hash.new
hon['bob::params::search'] = Hash.new
hoh.each do |key,value|
  value.each do |k, v|
    hon['bob::params::search'][k] = hoh['bob::params::search_vol_grp'][k].merge! (hob['bob::params::search_q_broker'][k])
  end
end
```

I also updated the 2nd hash to use a fixnum rather then a string as indicated by Darshan.

Thanks for all the pointers guys!

Comment: Does the answer in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10691318/merge-some-complex-hashes-in-ruby?rq=1) help at all?

Comment: If you're using Rails, try out `deep_merge`: http://apidock.com/rails/Hash/deep_merge

Comment: Those are not valid Ruby expressions (even besides the invalid assignment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this...

```
1[2].merge(2[2])
```

You need to merge the inner hashes.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Working through this now.

Answer (score 1):

Giving your Hashes valid variable names, closing the Hashes, and making the second Hash use a Fixnum rather than a String for the top-level key, this appears to do what you want:

```
h1 = {2=>{"search_group_id"=>2, "vol_ids"=>"2,627,628", "num_shards"=>32,
          "num_replicas"=>1}}
h2 = {2=>{"master_host"=>"hsrchq01p1", "master_port"=>"61616",
           "slave_host"=>"hsrchq01p2", "slave_port"=>"61616"}}

h1.merge(h2){|key, first, second| first.merge(second)}
# => {2=>{"search_group_id"=>2, "vol_ids"=>"2,627,628", "num_shards"=>32,
#         "num_replicas"=>1, "master_host"=>"hsrchq01p1", "master_port"=>"61616",
#         "slave_host"=>"hsrchq01p2", "slave_port"=>"61616"}}
```

Comment: Having the key as `2` in the first one and `"2"` in the second is a nuisance to say the least. You'd have to account for that here somehow.

Comment: @tadman Given the other issues that made the code as presented invalid, I presumed that to be another error, not a true representation of the data to be dealt with.  Of course you're right, and that may be something the OP has to deal with.

Comment: Just adding it as a caveat as people with a background in other languages like PHP and Perl might not realize that these are two different things in Ruby as there's no auto-conversion applied.

Comment: @DarshanComputing Thanks for the tip re: the fixnum issue.